# Is it Possible to Use data in a .txt file as variables in a conditional statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just wondering if it would be possible for data in an opened .txt file to be used in a conditional statement as variables? Internet Explorer says if you had a list of numbers in a saved text file, but only want to display odd integers in a list in python. (I've only been programming for a few months as a newbie) How would you go about doing this?

Thank.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Posting a sample file and the code you have tried so far would vastly improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may use data read from a text file to drive a conditional statement. You must `.read()` the data and store it in a variable. Like so:

```
with open("input.txt") as input_file:
    text = input_file.read()
strings = text.split()
numbers = [int(item) for item in strings]
```

Now all of your numbers are stored in the list `numbers`. To print out only the odd ones:

```
odds = [number for number in numbers if number % 2 == 1]
print(odds)
```

Or, if you prefer not to use list comprehensions:

```
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 1:
        print(number)
```